# Python for loop over matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem with a small python program to cross-match two arrays. As a side note, I'm learning to code in Python in these days, so I assume I'm making some incredibly trivial mistake here.
Basically, I want to open two .txt files, create a 2D array from each of them, and compare them to see if they have common elements.
So far, I did something like this

```
#creating arrays from files
models  = np.genfromtxt('models.txt', dtype='float')
data    = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', dtype='float')

#obtaining the number of rows in each array
mod_nrows = models.shape[0]
data_nrows = data.shape[0]

#checking line by line if there are ay matches
for i in range(mod_nrows)
    for j in range(data_nrows)
        do stuff....
```

but I'm getting the generic error

```
File "crossmatch.py", line 27
   for i in range(mod_nrows)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I thought the problem might be that

```
mod_nrows = models.shape[0]
```

doesn't return an `int` (which should be the argument of the function range()), and I tried to change the two for loops to

```
for i in range(int(mod_nrows))
    for j in range(int(data_nrows))
        do stuff....
```

but I'm still getting the same error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any for loop should end with a colon (:).

The colon is required primarily to enhance readability. Python docs explicitly mention [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-are-colons-required-for-the-if-while-def-class-statements)

```
#creating arrays from files
models  = np.genfromtxt('models.txt', dtype='float')
data    = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', dtype='float')

#obtaining the number of rows in each array
mod_nrows = models.shape[0]
data_nrows = data.shape[0]

#checking line by line if there are ay matches
for i in range(mod_nrows):
    for j in range(data_nrows):
        do stuff....
```